# how to add new column in existing table in entity framework in xamarin shared project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, shared-project

I am using entity framework SQLite and I think it will use the concept of migration, as of now I have tried using create a new class library and creating the migration but I am always getting build failed error.
I think I am not going through the correct way, help will apricated even I am getting any blogs or reference for the shared projected

Comment: Which problem do you meet when you add the new column to the table?

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT i am getting "no such column is present in table".

Comment: You can check your name of the columns whether there are any spaces in the name. Please make the name right.